# server.session.cookie.max-age doesn't seem to work

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I added in my configuration the following property:

```
server.session.cookie.max-age=3600
```

The `Set-Cookie` HTTP header is:

```
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=3407BD3E1C7153D70EFC5DBD16B059E4; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
```

So it seems like Spring ignores this property. Is it deprecated? If not, why isn't it working?

Here's my configuration:

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .successForwardUrl("/")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/", true)
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
            .invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .and()
            .rememberMe()
            .key("key")
            .tokenValiditySeconds(86400);
}
```

Comment: spring-boot-starter-parent is 2.1.4.RELEASE and spring-boot-starter-web is actually 2.1.0.RELEASE

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With Spring Boot 2.1.4 you have to use the property `server.servlet.session.cookie.max-age` instead of `server.session.cookie.max-age`, see [Spring Boot Reference Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.4.RELEASE/reference/html/common-application-properties.html):

> **Appendix A. Common application properties**
>
> Various properties can be specified inside your `application.properties` file, inside your `application.yml` file, or as command line switches. This appendix provides a list of common Spring Boot properties and references to the underlying classes that consume them.
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> # EMBEDDED SERVER CONFIGURATION (ServerProperties)
> [...]
> server.servlet.session.cookie.max-age= # Maximum age of the session cookie. If a duration suffix is not specified, seconds will be used.
> ```

and [Spring Boot 2.0.0 RC1 Configuration Changelog](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0.0-RC1-Configuration-Changelog).